# How to make text fade-out and new text fade in on change?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a marquee for my website, however, I am stuck with one thing.

I have made it so every 20 seconds the text inside the marquee changes, however, I don't like how the text just changes. I would like to make it so the old text fades out and the new text fades in.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Relatively new to this :)
Here is the script that changes the text:

```js
let text = [ "example 1", "example 2", "example 3", "example 4"];
let counter = 0;
setInterval(change, 20000);

function change() {
    document.getElementById("fadeEl").innerHTML = text[counter];
    counter++;
    if(counter >= text.length) {
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<span id="fadeEl">random starting text</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can have two classes in your CSS:

```js
const text = ["example 1", "example 2", "example 3", "example 4"];
let counter = 0;

setInterval(change, 5000);

function change() {
  document.getElementById("fadeEl").setAttribute("class", "text-fade");

  setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById("fadeEl").innerHTML = text[counter];
    document.getElementById("fadeEl").setAttribute("class", "text-show");
  }, 1000)

  counter++;

  if (counter >= text.length) {
    counter = 0;
  }
}
```

```css
.text-show {
  color: black;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.text-fade {
  color: black;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<span id="fadeEl" class="text-show">example 1</span>
```

don't forget your 1-second `setTimout` in your function to handle the fade out before you change the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `transitionend` event...

```js
const
  marqueeLike = document.querySelector('#marquee-like')
, textList = (function* () { // IIGFE
    const arr = [ 'example 1', 'example 2', 'example 3', 'example 4' ];
    let   idx = -1;
    for(;;) {
      idx = ++idx % arr.length;
      yield arr[idx]; 
      yield arr[idx]; 
    }}())
, marqueeChange =_=> {
    marqueeLike.textContent = textList.next().value;
    marqueeLike.classList.toggle('fade-in');    
    };

marqueeLike.ontransitionend = marqueeChange;
// window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', marqueeChange ); // doesn't work with SO snippet...  
setTimeout(marqueeChange, 500 );  // to replace DOMContentLoaded  for SO snippet demo...
```

```css
#marquee-like {
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight : bold;
  font-size   : 20px;
  opacity     : 0;
  transition  : opacity 1s ease;
  }
#marquee-like.fade-in {
  opacity : 1;
  }
```

```html
<p id="marquee-like"> Text Here! </p>
```